# Enable constraints of database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, constraints

I am working on SQL Server 2008

I am using this query to disable constraints of entire database,I think this query is right

to disable-

```
 USE geoAllCase; 
 GO EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

It ran successfully

to enable

```
USE geoAllCase; 
GO EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

After that the database copied successfully with data, but when again I was going to enable all constraints I stucked with this error msg, how can I **enable Foreign Key constraints over existing data of database**

error msg-

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 
>   The ALTER TABLE statement
>   conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_MP_GN_LE_V". The
>   conflict occurred in database "geo2", table "dbo.TGEO_EDGE_V", column
>   'GEO_EDGE_UID'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column GEO_EDGE_UID in table dbo.TGEO_EDGE_V contains data that is violating your FK_MP_GN_LE_V foreign key constraint. There is no way you are going to re-enable that constraint with out first cleaning your data.

Comment: well, i don't know your business rules/requirements. So i authoritatively suggest how you might work around it with out more details

Comment: This sis why it was a poor idea to get rid of the constraints in the first place. It is better to resolve data problems before you put data into the databases. You have data that is meaningless since it doesn't have data that relates to a parent record.  Now you need to resolve the data issue that you skipped resolving in the first place.

Comment: Its all right.... but actually I have to do in this way otherwise I got many issues. You pls tell me is there any **sql query** which enable constraints with keeping original records??

Comment: @HLGEM....I am using a query to enable constraints is- 'GO EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"'. Actually in the parent table only two records and in child table there are three records, so what should I do becoz I have to keep all the records and constraints and enable constraints too.